# Loading older Pickle file - Scipy Attribute Error

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-science, pickle

I was given a pickle file, which was created a few months ago. I am trying to load it but I get the following error:

```
pandas.read_pickle("exploring_G_and_w_and_J.pkl")
Traceback (most recent call last):

  Cell In[12], line 1
    simulations = pandas.read_pickle("exploring_G_and_w_and_J.pkl")

  File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\pickle.py:213 in read_pickle
    return pc.load(handles.handle, encoding=None)

  File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\compat\pickle_compat.py:275 in load
    return up.load()

  File ~\anaconda3\lib\pickle.py:1213 in load
    dispatch[key[0]](self)

  File ~\anaconda3\lib\pickle.py:1538 in load_stack_global
    self.append(self.find_class(module, name))

  File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\compat\pickle_compat.py:206 in find_class
    return super().find_class(module, name)

  File ~\anaconda3\lib\pickle.py:1582 in find_class
    return _getattribute(sys.modules[module], name)[0]

  File ~\anaconda3\lib\pickle.py:331 in _getattribute
    raise AttributeError("Can't get attribute {!r} on {!r}"

AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'SpearmanrResult' on <module 'scipy.stats._stats_py' from 'C:\\Users\\orest\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\scipy\\stats\\_stats_py.py'>
```

Scipy is installed. From googling around it seems that the problem is with the version of packages but I don't know which package and what version I should use. The person who gave me the package has formated his PC, so we cannot figure out his environment.

Edit:

The problem persists even when I try to load the files directly through pickle

```
with open("exploring_G_and_w_and_J.pkl", "rb") as f:
    simulations = pickle.load(f)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  Cell In[15], line 2
    simulations = pickle.load(f)

AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'SpearmanrResult' on <module 'scipy.stats._stats_py' from 'C:\\Users\\orest\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\scipy\\stats\\_stats_py.py'>
```

Comment: in my PC: python 3.10.9, pandas 1.5.3, scipy 1.10.0, pickle 4.0.      For the other PC it is not possible. Only thing he remembers is that he installed most packages in early 2022.